# video requestFullScreen not working on mobile devices using Video.js

Tags: android, ios, html, video, video.js

The goal of what we are trying to do is get the user to click a link and then play a video fullscreen on mobile devices.

I am unable to get the below code working consistently on mobile devices using Video.js. We are using brightcove so I need to set the video element source dynamically. I can get the fullscreen working if the source is set initially, but even then it isn't consistent. We are testing on Android (Chrome, FireFox and the default browser) and iOS. For what it is worth we do not need to support desktop on this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="video.dev.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264">
</video>
<a href="#" id="play" onclick="playVideo();" style="">play</a>
<script>

    var video = videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
    });
    video.on("fullscreenchange",eventTriggered);
    video.on("play",eventTriggered);

    function playVideo(){
        video.src({src:'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',type:'video/mp4'});
        video.play();
        video.requestFullScreen();
        return false;
    }
    function eventTriggered(e){
        console.log("event:"+e.type);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code variations**

The below code works on FireFox and the default browser but not android. iOS plays but does not trigger the fullscreenchange event.

```
    var video = videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
        this.on("fullscreenchange",eventTriggered);
        this.on("play",eventTriggered);
        this.src({src:'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',type:'video/mp4'});
    });

    function playVideo(){
        video.play();
        video.requestFullScreen();
        return false;
    }
```

This as well has sporadic support

```
    var video = videojs("example_video_1", {}, function(){
    });

    video.on("fullscreenchange",eventTriggered);
    video.on("play",eventTriggered);
    video.src({src:'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',type:'video/mp4'});

    function playVideo(){
        video.play();
        video.requestFullScreen();
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT:
On further investigation, on iOS it appears the native tech is used. It doesn't seem to manually trigger `this.trigger('fullscreenchange');` as the alternatives do.

Lines 3519-3523 video.dev.js

```
  } else if (this.tech.supportsFullScreen()) {
    // we can't take the video.js controls fullscreen but we can go fullscreen
    // with native controls
    this.techCall('enterFullScreen');
  } else {
```